# Is there a way to retain the time zone info in the result of this JSONPath query?

Tags: c#, json.net, jsonpath

I'm using JSONPath queries (and NewtonSoft.Json.Linq) to pull properties from user-supplied JSON and I've run into an issue with the JSON "Date" type.

Example code (can be fiddled with at https://dotnetfiddle.net/SqslzX):

```
    string json = "{ \"MyTime\":\"2014-04-20T18:15:11-0700\" }";
    var sourceToken = JToken.Parse(json);
    var myTimeToken = sourceToken.SelectToken("MyTime");
    var myTimeOffset = myTimeToken.ToObject<DateTimeOffset>();
    Console.WriteLine(myTimeToken.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(myTimeOffset.ToString());
```

The output (run in .net Fiddle) looks like:

```
4/21/2014 1:15:11 AM
4/21/2014 1:15:11 AM +00:00
```

I know these times are correct for the local time zone. But I'd like to find a way to retain the original time and offset values, if possible.

Comment: I think extra field should be added to json which tells the timezone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that by default the serializer setting for [`DateParseHandling`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer_DateParseHandling.htm) is `DateParseHandling.DateTime`. We need to use a method that allows for customizing serializer settings, so `Parse` won't cut it. You could use `DeserializeObject` to a .NET type, but I'm guessing you don't have a strong type. This works and still lets you use LINQ methods:

```
string json = "{ \"MyTime\":\"2014-04-20T18:15:11-0700\" }";

JsonReader reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(json));
reader.DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.DateTimeOffset; // this is what we need to change

var sourceObject = JObject.Load(reader);

var myTimeToken = sourceObject.SelectToken("MyTime");

var myTimeOffset = myTimeToken.ToObject<DateTimeOffset>();

Console.WriteLine(myTimeOffset.ToString());
//prints: 4/20/2014 6:15:11 PM -07:00
```